# How to classify your fluid is a transitioning from a liquid to gas from numerical computation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, navier-stokes, states-of-matter

I saw at one time that if the kinetic energy/potential energy of the gas was approaching 1 then the gas is becoming a liquid. I can't find the reference where I found that though (it was on stack overflow).

I guess in general I'm interested if you can track from solving the NSE numerically when you are transitioning from a gas phase to liquid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must mean this question;
[Potential vs Kinetic Energy of Particles in Gas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78085/potential-vs-kinetic-energy-of-particles-in-gas)

This is very interesting approach. The ratio of Kinetic energy (inertia) and Potential energy (field) is commonly named as a Froude-number. And indeed you can solve NSE numerically to get this transition. I have actually made this derivation. Basically it shows you that the limit is $Fr=\sqrt3$. This Q&A is related; 
[How should energy loss in a hydraulic jump be calculated?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466964/how-should-energy-loss-in-a-hydraulic-jump-be-calculated)

And the full derivation can be found here;
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325677372_Navier-Stokes_existency_and_smoothness_problem_-The_Answer_word-txt

Comment: Thank you for the response- very interesting indeed I will look deeper.